# Need to store <?fo:page-number?> inside a variable

Tags: bi-publisher

I need to print a qrcode that is a concat by a code that is stored in the xml tag and the actual page number, because I need to pass the string with xmltag and page number in the `<?format-barcode:DATATEXT;'qrcode';'MyBarcodeEncoder'?>` but i can't figure out how to do that.

I tried to store the `<?fo:page-number?>` inside a variable and then concatenate that with my xmltag code but i think it's impossible.
Anyone knows some workaround to do that? 
thanks

Comment: Is your barcode dependant on page number? Are you page-breaking after the barcode? Is it just one barcode per page? Show us a full example of what you are doing/trying please.

Comment: @PeterPaff yes i need the actual page number, yes it's just one qrcode per page. i have a code inside a xml tag like "AAA_0000000_11111" that i need to encode into a qrcode but before that i need to concat the page number to that code like "AAA_0000000_11111_page-number" did you understand my issue? i'm able to concat that inside the field but then when i need to use the command '<?format-barcode:DATATEXT;'qrcode';'MyBarcodeEncoder'?>' i'm not able to pass that concatenate string in the "DATATEXT" parmeter.